# Game keeps deleting bUse Joystick=1 from ini file

Tags: controllers, fallout-new-vegas

Title pretty much says it. New Vegas removed the option to use a controller and after some googling i readded the line bUse Joystick 1 in the ini file, and set it back to read only. But every single time I start the game up it removes the line again and again, even though it is set to read only, this happened after doing some modding, any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: "*this happened after doing some modding*"? How about diasbling the mod(s)?